# Implement a higher-order function called `processLastItem`

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I'm working on homework and I'm completely lost.
This is the question:

> Implement a higher-order function called `processLastItem`.
>   It takes two arguments:
>
> - @param stringList array of strings.
> - @param callback function that takes a string as its argument.
> - @returns the result of invoking `callback` with the LAST element in `stringList`."

They're throwing this at us without having taught it yet so I have no idea where to even start, can someone show me at least where to begin?

Comment: What *do* they have taught? Can you show us your attempt at writing the function, please - even if it is not complete? At what part exactly are you stuck? Surely you do know to begin with `function processLastItem(…`.

Comment: It's not really possible to to answer this without just doing your homework since you didn't explain how you'e having trouble. Can you edit this to include a question *you* have? For example, you say you don't know where to start…does that mean you don't know what a function or a string is? If you do know those you would probably start with `function processLastItem(stringList, callback){...`

Answer (score 3):

A higher order function is basically a function that either returns another function as its result, or takes in a function as a parameter. Here's an example of an implementation of `forEach`, which is a higher order function. This is pretty useless for actual production code, but hopefully illustrates the concept:

```
function forEach(array, callbackFunction) {
    for (const item of array) {
        // note we are now calling the passed in function
        callbackFunction(item);
    }
}
```

So what you need to do with your homework is take this example and pair that together with code to get the last element of an array. Hopefully that shouldn't be as hard with a clear example.